# Laravel [login-message] not found exception

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I'm getting this error

[image: this]

> InvalidArgumentException in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php
>   line 137: View [login-message] not found.

**EDIT:**

C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstProject\app\Http\Controllers\LoginMessa‌​geController.php:

```
public function index() { 
    $company_name= Session::get('company_sess.company_name'); 
    //return view('login-message'); 
    if ($company_name) { 
        return redirect()->guest($company_name.'/login'); 
    } 
    else { 
        return view('login-message');
    }
}
```

Comment: provide more about your exception?

Comment: Where is situated view `login-message` and how you try to use it?

Comment: @Ismail Malik I has inserted this code in question. Please say where is `login-message` situated?

Comment: actually i didn't find login-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its saying that it cant find a view named `login-message`. You need to make sure that in your views folder you actually have view with filename `login-message.blade.php`